# Use https for accessing Docker private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a private registry, that it's accessed through the https protocol.
But Kubernetes + Docker, always tries to use the http protocol http://myserver.com:8080 instead of https://myserver.com:8080.

How to force https protocol?

Snippet of my `yaml` file that declares a Pod:

```
  containers:
    - name: apl
      image: myserver.com:8080/myimage
```

Details of my environment:

- CentOS 7.3
- Docker 18.06
- Kubernetes (Minikube) 1.13.1

Error message in Kubernetes logs:

```
  Normal   Pulling    30s (x4 over 2m2s)  kubelet, minikube  pulling image "docker.mydomain.com:30500/vision-ssh"
  Warning  Failed     30s (x4 over 2m2s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "docker.mydomain.com:30500/vision-ssh": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get http://docker.mydomain.com:30500/v2/: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
  Warning  Failed     30s (x4 over 2m2s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     19s (x6 over 2m2s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    4s (x7 over 2m2s)   kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "docker.fccma.com:30500/vision-ssh"
```

If I try to specify the protocol in the name of the image, it complains:

```
couldn't parse image reference "https://docker.mydomain.com:30500/vision-ssh": invalid reference format
```

Followed this [guide](https://robertbrem.github.io/Microservices_with_Kubernetes/03_Docker_registry/01_Setup_a_docker_registry/) in order to create the image registry.  It is already secured (HTTPS protocol and protected by user/password).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `/etc/hosts` file, the server `docker.mydomain.com` is mapped to 127.0.0.1.  I've read in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#insecure-registries) that local registries are always considered insecure.
If I use a name that is mapped to the external IP, then Docker tries `https`.

Answer (score 1):

Your private docker registry might not be secured. If it is secured private registry it always use https otherwise it refers to http.

For more details refer doc:

```
Docker uses the https:// protocol to communicate with a registry, unless the registry is allowed to be accessed over an insecure connection. Refer to the insecure registries section for more information.
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#insecure-registries

So to force https , secure your registry. There are many articles available on net to secure your registry.

Comment: It is already secured.  Followed this [guide](https://robertbrem.github.io/Microservices_with_Kubernetes/03_Docker_registry/01_Setup_a_docker_registry/).

Answer (score 0):

Run https proxy service fronting the container  registry service. Look at nginx as https proxy